# Git: change branch in the middle of solving conflicts (stash doesn't work)

Tags: git

```
git version 2.6.3.windows.1
```

I have a `pull request` I need to to do.
So I checkout out to a new branch (`pull_feature_branch`). did the `pull` request, which resolved in **many** conflicts.

No problem- I just need time to fix them, Should take me a few days.

But suddenly I discover a bug which I must attend to- in the main branch.
But I can't checkout out from my *pull_feature_branch* branch to my main branch.

Usually I *stash* my uncommited changes in other branch- which allow me to checkout to main branch to fix bug .

But right now *stash* doesn't work-

```
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
Cannot save the current index state
```

There must be a way for me to halt my conflict procedure, fix the bug, and then return to fixing the conflicts.

Now I know I can "kinda" solve it (*avoid* is the more suitable word) by creating another project folder (either by cloning the project or using `worktree` command- see [CodeWizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34533239/2502605))
And use one folder for solving conflicts, and the other for solving the bug.

I'm looking for a way to be able to change branch, within the same folder.

To summarize: I did a *pull* request which made many *conflics* and now I'm "stuck" in current conflicts branch without the ability to change branch.

Comment: What's wrong with completely avoiding a problem?

Comment: @jthill monkey patch things is also avoiding a problem.
It creates another folder for me to remember, I prefer not to add another folder. If I add a folder every time- I will lose track of them all- That's why I want to keep it in the same folder

Comment: @jthill what's the need of a command to switch branches when you can just create a new directory?

Comment: @Roko You're planning on spending several *days* just resolving conflicts. You're worried that you might end up working on so many things at once that you won't be able to keep track of all the folders. Sounds like you've got some workflow issues that no amount of Git-fu will help with!

Comment: @pqnet one-clone-per-effort is actually not a bad way to work, serially reusing a worktree is convenient when they're trivial or don't overlap in time. Clones are dirt cheap, they're made for this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple.

Under the `contrib/workdir` directory of Git's source code, you will find a  git command named `git new-workdir`.

This command allow you to work simultaneously on several branches side by side.
What the function does is simply creating a shallow copy of your `git` folder (type tree .git in the new folder to see where it actually points to) and you will see that it points to the original git folder.
In the new folder you can create new commits, branches and more, and you will see it in all of your `new-workdir` folders since they share the "same" git repo.

## Demo: (Unix)

1. add the `contrib/workdir` to your path
2. set execution flags to the `git-new-workdir`
3. navigate to your current git repository

   ```
   git new-workdir . my_new_path 
   cd my_new_path
   tree .git ( you should see links to the original git repository)
   git checkout -b new_branch
   git branch (your new branch is listed)
   cd original_path
   git branch (the new branch is listed but the current branch is the original branch)
   ```

:-)

[image: Here is a screenshot of the 2 diffent branches]

Git 2.5 will contain a feature allowing you to have multiple working directory without using this script (`git checkout --to=$path`).

Comment: I'm using get 2.6.3- So I don't need that script?

Comment: Thank you for answering- If I'm already using a new folder- I can just clone the whole project- finish the conflicts in the new folder, then merge them.
No way to achieve that without using a different project folder?

Comment: Nope. and if its not working simply follow the demo steps and it will work.
It will allow you to work on many branches simultaneously

Comment: You can also clone it again, but you don't need to , this is what this feature is for - to save the clone. if you clone you will have to commit your changes and to pull them to see the same cod between the 2 clones, using workdir they share the same branches and code

Comment: Read more about it here:
https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows

Comment: While this answer is helpful- my desire is not to create a another folder, and have two different folder, one responsible for each branch- I'll update my question.